# Dar un estilo personalizado a MenuStrip

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola con todos estoy tratando de personalizar un menu con colores diferentes al que viene por defecto hasta el momento e podido cambiar la parte que carga al inicio pero cuando hago click en el menu me muestra de la como si fuera el que viene por defecto espero que me puedan ayudar dejare acontinuacion algunas imagenes para que puedan comprenderme.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: winforms o wpf?

Comment: esta en winforms

Comment: comentario al margen> estamos en 2018, no hay motivo para usar windows forms, y si debes hacerlo no te desgastes cambiando la UI. El resultado siempre sera muy dependiente de los settings del usuario y aunque es posible lograrlo... hay una razón por la cual venden controles ya tematizables. Requiere esfuerzo crearlos, bastante esfuerzo.